# Recovering a (only partially) forgotten LUKS passphrase

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, password-recovery

I am currently trying to access an old netbook with some files that I would like to go through. The problem is that I can not quite remember the password for the disk encryption and as a result keep getting the "cryptsetup failed bad password or options?" message.

Even though I can not remember the entire password I can remember large parts of it. I am also fairly certain about many characters NOT occurring, so much so that I can narrow down the possible combinations to (hopefully) less than a billion or so.

Is that going to do me any good and how would I go about recovering my password given the information that I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to get a [LUKS bruteforcer](https://github.com/glv2/bruteforce-luks) (many exist) and tailor it to your needs. In the README you should be able to estimate the effort required; for example it might say that every character you add in the range A-Z will increase solving time by X hours on the reference CPU, and so on.

Comment: Thank you! I am going to have to write some code to enumerate the possibilities while using some of the substrings and other things I half remember, but now I am confident that I will eventually manage to narrow the search space down enough to find the answer in a reasonable time.